# no module named numbapro

Tags: python, numba-pro

I ran this code I read on a CUDA Python intro page:-

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from numbapro import vectorize

@vectorize(["float32(float32, float32)"], target='gpu')
def VectorAdd(a, b):
        return a + b

def main():
    N = 32000000

    A = np.ones(N, dtype=np.float32)
    B = np.ones(N, dtype=np.float32)
    C = np.zeros(N, dtype=np.float32)

    start = timer()
    C = VectorAdd(A, B)
    vectoradd_timer = timer() - start

    print("C[:5] = " + str(C[:5]))
    print("C[-5:] = " + str(C[-5:]))

    print("VectorAdd took %f seconds" % vectoradd_timer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And I am getting the following error on terminal:-

```
dtn34@dtn34-ubuntu:~/Python$ python asd.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asd.py", line 3, in <module>
    from numbapro import vectorize
ImportError: No module named numbapro
```

It was supposed to run the code using the gpu but I am getting that error. I've installed anaconda, updated conda, installed accelerate using conda, installed cudatoolkit, installed numba using conda.
I tried compiling it using both python2 and python3

What do I do?

Comment: FYI: https://docs.anaconda.com/numbapro/

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser  
So...what do I do? Should I use numba in place of numbapro? Or accelerate?

Comment: if you have installed numba and anaconda accelerate, try just changing `from numbapro import vectorize` to `from numba import vectorize`.  See [here](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.15.1/examples.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it. As pointed out by WarrenWeckesser and Robert Crovella, NumbaPro has been deprecated and all the features were moved to numba.
So instead of numbapro you are supposed to write numba

```
from numba import vectorize
```

Also the target needs to be set to 'cuda' instead of 'gpu'

```
@vectorize(["float32(float32, float32)"], target='cuda')
def VectorAdd(a, b):
        return a + b
```

Comment: Thank you that was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run it in both (CPU and GPU) after modifying, the CPU is faster than GPU

first one in CPU:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import  default_timer as timer
# from numba import vectorize
# @vectorize(["float32(float32, float32)"], target='cuda')

def VectorAdd(a ,b):
    return a + b

def main():
    N = 32000000
    A = np.ones(N, dtype=np.float32)
    B = np.ones(N, dtype=np.float32)
    C = np.ones(N, dtype=np.float32)

    srart = timer()
    C = VectorAdd(A,B)
    vectoradd_time = timer() - srart
    print ("C[:5] = " + str(C[:5]))
    print ("C[:-5] = " + str(C[:-5]))
    print ('vectoradd_time %f second' % vectoradd_time)
if __name__== '__main__':
    main()
```

the time:

```
vectoradd_time 0.046457 second
```

the second one in GPU:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from numba import vectorize

@vectorize(["float32(float32, float32)"], target='cuda')


def VectorAdd(a, b):
        return a + b

def main():
    N = 32000000

    A = np.ones(N, dtype=np.float32)
    B = np.ones(N, dtype=np.float32)
    C = np.zeros(N, dtype=np.float32)

    start = timer()
    C = VectorAdd(A, B)
    vectoradd_timer = timer() - start

    print("C[:5] = " + str(C[:5]))
    print("C[-5:] = " + str(C[-5:]))

    print("VectorAdd took %f seconds" % vectoradd_timer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the time:

```
VectorAdd took 0.240731 seconds
```

this result depend on the specifications of your CPU.