# Exception: Version mismatch: this is the 'cffi' package version 1.13.1,

Tags: python, pip, numba

I tried to run the code using CUDA, I got this error, it seems something wrong in the system

the full code: I got it [CUDACast #10a - Your First CUDA Python Program](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPQnFXD7DxM) and [no module named numbapro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48326314/no-module-named-numbapro)

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from numba import vectorize

@vectorize(["float32(float32, float32)"], target='cuda')


def VectorAdd(a, b):
        return a + b

def main():
    N = 32000000

    A = np.ones(N, dtype=np.float32)
    B = np.ones(N, dtype=np.float32)
    C = np.zeros(N, dtype=np.float32)

    start = timer()
    C = VectorAdd(A, B)
    vectoradd_timer = timer() - start

    print("C[:5] = " + str(C[:5]))
    print("C[-5:] = " + str(C[-5:]))

    print("VectorAdd took %f seconds" % vectoradd_timer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the output:

> Exception: Version mismatch: this is the 'cffi' package version
>   1.13.1, located in '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi/api.pyc'.  When we import
>   the top-level '_cffi_backend' extension module, we get version 1.5.2,
>   located in
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_cffi_backend.x86_64-linux-gnu.so'. 
>   The two versions should be equal; check your installation.

maybe this reason:

```
$which pip
/usr/bin/pip
```

Comment: It is not related to cuda. Just check the version of two packages it is complaining

Comment: Check this https://github.com/pogodevorg/pgoapi/issues/46

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to try by removing all the cffi packages separately and installed version `1.5.2`.

```
sudo pip install cffi==1.5.2
```

Or you can make sure the version is consistent by updating the old version.

```
sudo apt-get install python-cffi
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 6):

updating pip to the latest version solved my problem.

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```